# Custom Drop Down Menu in a Custom Word Content Control

Tags: ms-word, office-interop

I'm able to create a DropDown ContentControl in word such that a user can select an item from the drop down and that item becomes the text displayed in the ContentControl. However I've noticed that when you create a citation that drop down list contains command items that can launch dialogs. Is there any way to replicate this behaviour but with custom content controls that launch custom dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is impossible as mentioned in the link below because:

> This isn't a "standard" content control. This is something Word puts around a Citation field (and around Date fields and some other kinds). But the functionality is Word-internal and proprietary. It's not something that's exposed in the API. IOW, you can't do that, I'm afraid...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/40542235-1a32-45e6-9aef-55709021ce53/how-do-i-create-a-contentcontrol-with-a-menu-like-when-inserting-a-placeholder?forum=worddev